# How can I save multiple choice values in a SQL-Table? How should be the table like?

Tags: mysql, sql

how can I save the multiple choice values in a SQL-Table? Is that possible at all?

I have to save the HTML-Checkbox values in a SQL-Table. The question will be, "what kind of icecream do you like?"

- choice 1: Strawberry
- choice 2: Blueberry
- choice 3: Chocolate
- choice 4: Vanilla

(Multiple choice is possible)

My SQL-Table has two columns, id and sortOfIcecream. Is that correct?

Comment: If you know the four choices and they do not change, then you can just have four columns.

Comment: Sure, your table can be as you indicated: `id, flavor`. What you do with that table depends on your needs of course.

Comment: Note that for your html table you will want to set the `id` column style to hidden: `<td style="display:none;">`

Comment: Or just not return that value at all, however that is outside of the scope of the question. Additionally, he's asking how to implement his needs as described.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I know this is the simplest solution, but I will disagree with you on this one. Next time we will have to show OP how to normalise the DB.

Answer (score 2):

You should implement three tables:

```
    CREATE TABLE customer (
    customer_id int - Autoincrement,
    customer_name varchar(100)
    )

    CREATE TABLE icecream (
    icecream_id int - Autoincrement,
    flavor varchar(100)
    )

    CREATE TABLE cust_flavors (
    customer_id int,
    icecream_id int,
    preference int
    )
```

The `cust_flavors` table contains all the selections each customer makes. To list a customer's selections, use:

```
    SELECT c.customer_name, i.flavor, cf.preference 
        FROM customer c LEFT JOIN cust_flavors cf
        ON c.customer_id = cf.customer_id
        LEFT JOIN icecream  i
        ON cf.icecream_id = i.icecream_id
      WHERE c.customer_id = @customer
      ORDER BY cf.preference
```

The `preference` column would be used if there is a priority to be assigned to the flavors. That is, the customer likes Vanilla more than Blueberry (if that's important to know).

Comment: I believe this is the most precise and expert solution; as you can see from the select query, it can get complicated in that respect, but this is far outweighed from the perspectives of maintainability, viewing any individual table (there will be less clutter), and is one of the most easily optimized as well.

Comment: I think the only improvement that even could be made upon this would be to utilize foreign keys so any removals could cascade.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend utilizing Dashier's answer, but I will show other methodologies as well.

---

Assuming you've already sorted out how the data is specifically coming in, this is a fairly trivial process.

You'll have variables similar to `$likes_strawberry` for all the flavors, and you can store it in the database as described, just over several rows.

Assuming the ID column is the ID of the user who likes the flavor, and the user likes several flavors, you could insert a row for each flavor liked, such as:

```
userID | flavor
---------------
1234   | Strawberry
1234   | Vanilla
1234   | Blueberry
```

This is similar to Dashier's answer, however only with 2 tables (user table, and flavors like by users table). This makes it a little bit simpler, but you do sacrifice some more control over maintainability of the list of active flavors.

---

A slightly different approach, as Gordon suggested, would be to use multiple columns and just 1 row per user. This would save you some overhead on inserting, but could cost you as you add available flavors, you change flavors that are available, or any such thing.

You would convert the variables to booleans and save it like so:

```
userID | likesStrawberry | likesBlueberry | likesVanilla
1234   | 1               | 0              | 1
4321   | 0               | 1              | 1
```

As you can see, each time you add a flavor to your menu, you have to add a column. This makes the table messy and rather difficult to maintain. This would generally be considered poor practice.

Comment: Of course, using static columns for the `flavor` data is not really maintainable. As soon as the code is implemented, the client will say they just added mint chip!

Comment: I agree with you, just wanted to demonstrate another suggested solution.

Answer (score -2):

ice_cream_flavours:

```
icf_id        INT(11) - Autoincrement
icf_flavour   VARCHAR(20)

icf_id | icf_flavour
-------+---------------
1      | Strawberry
2      | Blueberry
3      | Chocolate
4      | Vanilla
```

You could store the chosen values in multiple ways:

- As a comma seperated list (e.g. 2,3) in a VARCHAR field
- In a user_icf table (e.g. two records for a user if they've chosen 2 flavours)

Comment: "As a comma seperated list (e.g. 2,3) in a VARCHAR field" never do this

Comment: @tim Storing a CSV list of numeric values in a field wouldn't be my first choice but there are some use cases where this is actually very handy.

Comment: I think this could use a bit more clarification; you do not explain how items in your described table would link to users.